# SurveyJs Input element with addon

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, surveyjs

Am using ReactJS with surveyjs, I want to use an input element for a percentage value (%).
I wonder if there is a way of doing this:

- Using bootsrap addon or something like that with surveyjs inputs.
- Limit input value between 0 and 100.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure a question of type "text" to accept only numbers between 0 and 100. There are two options on the question that need to be set:

1. Add a validator of type "numeric" with minimum value of 0 and a maximum of 100.
2. Set the input type to "number" and set its min and max values to 0 and 100 respectively.

The resulting JSON should look like this:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "Enter percentage (0-100)",
     "validators": [
      {
       "type": "numeric",
       "minValue": 0,
       "maxValue": 100
      }
     ],
     "inputType": "number",
     "min": "0",
     "max": "100"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for the second part of my question, do you have any idea about the first part?

Comment: Do you mean the part about using a third-party component as an input field? Are you looking for a masked input with a percentage sign?

Comment: No I want to use an addon that shows the mark `%`, like in these examples:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Comment: Here's a react example on how to extend SurveyJS to add masking with % sign and other similar input options: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-night-v7mxr?file=/src/SurveyComponent.jsx I based this on the official example from here: https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=custom-widget-inputmask and it uses the following library: https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/

Comment: Thank you so much brother, I was looking for this for a while!